# Reading "X%"-formatted percentages into R

Tags: r, tidyr, readr

I am reading a CSV into R, where several columns contain percentages that are formatted as text strings with a percentage symbol at the end, e.g. "35%".  readr::read_csv() interprets these as character-type data, but I want the data to be numeric so I can perform analysis.

The following code achieves this, but seems like a lot of "hoops" to jump through.  Is there a standard function (or option for a function) that does the same thing?  There doesn't seem to be a relevant option in the read_csv() function.

```
convert_percentage_string <- function(percentage_string) {
  percentage_string %>%
    stringr::str_extract(., "[0-9]+") %>%
    as.numeric()
}

read_csv("my_data.csv") %>% 
  mutate_at(columns_with_percentages, convert_percentage_string)
```

Sample data:

```
tribble(~name, ~count, ~percentage, 
   "Alice", 4, "40%", 
   "Bob", 10, "65%", 
   "Carol", 15, "15%")
```

Expected result:

```
tribble(~name, ~count, ~percentage, 
       "Alice", 4, 40, 
       "Bob", 10, 65, 
       "Carol", 15, 15)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` and `readr` solution:

```
library(dplyr) # Version >= 1.0.0
library(readr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   mutate(across(where(~any(str_detect(.,"%"))), parse_number))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  count percentage
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Alice     4         40
2 Bob      10         65
3 Carol    15         15
```

Feel free to replace `any` with `all` if you prefer.

A benefit of this approach is it detects columns that have the `%` and only parses those. No need to know which columns need to be converted in advance.

Comment: Nice answer -- I had not thought of using str_detect to look for the columns that should be converted

Answer (score 2):

You can `sapply`the function `as.numeric` to the `percentage` column after removing the `%`sign from the numbers using `gsub`:

```
df$percentage <- sapply(gsub("(?<=\\d)%", "", df$percentage, perl = T), as.numeric)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer a `stringr` operation:

```
df$percentage <- sapply(str_extract(df$percentage, "\\d+"), as.numeric)
```

Result:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  count percentage
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Alice     4         40
2 Bob      10         65
3 Carol    15         15
```

Data:

```
df <- tribble(~name, ~count, ~percentage, 
        "Alice", 4, "40%", 
        "Bob", 10, "65%", 
        "Carol", 15, "15%")
```

Comment: This isn't obvious from the data example I provided, but there are actually several % columns in the data -- so a solution that "detects" which columns the conversion should be applied to is preferred

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a relevant option in read_csv:

```
read_csv("my_data.csv", col_types = cols(percentage = parse_number()))
```

and you could play with options like .default=col_guess() but `mutate(across(where(~any(str_detect` makes sense if you don't know which columns need to be converted, or if they change.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, first `grep` `"%"` columns into `.SD` and `lapply` the cleanup using `sub` and `as.numeric` over it with back-assignment.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('foo.csv')
dt[, (clm) := lapply(.SD, \(x) as.numeric(sub(x, pat='\\%', rep=''))), .SDcols={clm <- grep('%', dt)}]
dt
#     name count perc1 perc2
# 1: Alice     4    NA    60
# 2:   Bob    10    65    35
# 3: Carol    15    15    85
```

---

*Data:*

```
"name","count","perc1","perc2"
"Alice",4,NA," 60%"
"Bob",10," 65%"," 35%"
"Carol",15," 15%"," 85%"
```